# Top of Sum Using GroupBy

Tags: sql-server-2008

This query works and produces the data below:

```
select book_id, sum(quantity*order_price) as TExtCost
from bkorders.order_details
group by book_id
order by sum(quantity*order_price) desc

book_id                    TExtCost
```

---

```
   1128                                31909.34
   1401                                29966.00
   1108                                28410.30
.
.
.
```

The next step is to find the top (1) of these rows. I know I can't use nested aggregates but I'd like to do this:

select book_id, top (1) sum(quantity*order_price)) as TopSeller

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 * from (
select book_id, sum(quantity*order_price) as TExtCost
from bkorders.order_details
group by book_id
) a order by TExtCost desc
```

Comment: Hi Sergio and thanks very much. As a newbie I got close but then got (very) lost in the details.